# no schema available graphiql aspnet core

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, graphiql

I have my repo at https://github.com/nmarun/customergraph. When I run the application, I don't see any schema in the document explorer. I see a 404 when I look at the Network tab.

[image: 404 in Network tag]

I think I need to configure GraphiQl to call the /graphql endpoint to retrieve schema details and for some reason my HTTP POST action method is not getting hit at /graph endpoint.

All calls through postman are working fine when I hit the endpoint though: http://localhost:54068/graphql

Please assist.

```
using CustomerGraph.Models.Schema;
using CustomerGraph.Models.Services;
using GraphiQl;
using GraphQL;
using GraphQL.Server;
using GraphQL.Types;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace CustomerGraph
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            services.AddScoped<IDocumentExecuter, DocumentExecuter>();
            services.AddSingleton<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
            services.AddSingleton<CustomerType>();
            services.AddSingleton<AddressType>();
            services.AddSingleton<ContactType>();
            services.AddSingleton<ContactMethodType>();
            services.AddSingleton<CustomersQuery>();
            services.AddSingleton<CustomerSchema>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDependencyResolver>(
                c => new FuncDependencyResolver(type => c.GetRequiredService(type)));

            services.AddGraphQL(_ =>
            {
                _.EnableMetrics = true;
                _.ExposeExceptions = true;
            });

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            services.AddSingleton<ISchema>(new CustomerSchema(new FuncDependencyResolver(type => sp.GetService(type))));

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseGraphiQl("/graphiql");
            app.UseGraphQL<ISchema>("/graphql");
            app.UseGraphQLWebSockets<CustomerSchema>("/graphql");
            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: Updated my code so that Postman uses http://localhost:54068/graph endpoint now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the UseGraphIQL method, it assumes that the graphql endpoint is at the same place as the GraphQL api.

Fix it by replacing the following:

```
   app.UseGraphiQl("/graphiql");
            //app.UseGraphQL<CustomerSchema>("/graph");
            //app.UseGraphQLWebSockets<CustomerSchema>("/graphql");
            //app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
```

by:

```
   app.UseGraphiQl("/graphiql", "/graphql");
            app.UseGraphQL<CustomerSchema>("/graphql");
            app.UseGraphQLWebSockets<CustomerSchema>("/graphql");
            app.UseWebSockets();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch @MaartenDev